# How do I get an older version of Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

I’m playing Minecraft Bedrock Edition on a Nintendo Switch.

I want to get an older version of Bedrock Edition on my device.

I’ve seen answers for the Java Edition of Minecraft, but not Bedrock Edition.

How do I get an older version of MCBE on my device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Nintendo Switch, you will have to jailbreak your device and download an older Minecraft ROM. If you can find one. And you will not be able to play online.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t get an older version of Minecraft on the Switch. Don’t update it if you don’t want a new version!

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer is: you can’t. At least not easily.

I also have seen this done in Java Edition, but not in PE/BE.

Comment: thats most likely because its built into java

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Switch i don't think there is a possible way but I can say regarding PC versions of the game. Some launchers, allow you to pick the version you want. (It isn't illegal if you bought Minecraft on a device and have a Mojang account for example). You head to version in the launcher that allows this and choose what version you'd like to play.

Comment: "(It isn't illegal if you bought Minecraft on a device and have a Mojang account for example)" It IS illegal if the version you bought was for another platform. Having the Android version does not give you the right to the Switch or PC versions, for example.

Answer (score -4):

You need the old version's disc if you want to go back to the old version.

Comment: Can you explain more on what you do, or how this works, etc.?